# DATEADD SQL 2008 next time and next date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need help in select statement for sql 2008.
Below are my table:

```
ID Date                Time     Value
1  2014-01-01 00:00:00 00:00:00 A
2  2014-01-01 00:00:00 01:00:00 B
3  2014-01-01 00:00:00 02:00:00 C
4  2014-01-01 00:00:00 03:00:00 D
5  2014-01-01 00:00:00 04:00:00 E
  --- ff. ---
23 2014-01-01 00:00:00 23:00:00 Y
24 2014-01-01 00:00:00 00:00:00 Z
25 2014-01-02 00:00:00 00:00:00 AA
26 2014-01-02 00:00:00 01:00:00 AB
27 2014-01-02 00:00:00 02:00:00 AC
```

The question is, How can I know the next value for `Date` and `Time` using Select Statement with `DateAdd` function in SQL 2008?

If the date is 2014-06-01 and the time is 23:00, then the next date is still 2014-06-01. the next time is 00:00

If the date is 2014-06-01 and the time is 00:00, then the next date is 2014-06-02. the next time is 00:00

Advice please.
Thank you so much.

Regards,

Comment: You want to add hours?

Comment: You looking for distinct days?

Comment: Define your problem clearly and provide expected output.

Comment: Sorry if its not clear. I need to know, what is the next date & time.. if 2014-06-01 23:00, then the next date is still 2014-06-01, next time is 00:00:00. if 2014-06-01 00:00, then the next date is 2014-06-02, and the next time is 00:00:00. Hope this is clear. Thank u.

Comment: That seems really confusing to have two representations of midnight and to have the same representation mean two different midnights a day apart. Are you sure you want/need this? It's conventional to only have 00:00:00 represent the midnight at the start of a day (or, in some organizations, to avoid ever writing 00:00 so as to avoid ambiguity)

Comment: You also seem to have a few off-by-a-bit errors hiding in your sample data. If the pattern continues through the rows you've not shown, the row with `ID` `24` should have the 23:00:00 entry and letter X.

Comment: hello Damien_The_Unbeliever,, thank you for the correction. I just vote the good answer below. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the row with id = 24  is wrong, for the rest, the next value of each row is simply achieved :

```
select id, date, time, value, 
    cast(floor(cast(DateAdd(hour, 1, date + time) as float)) as datetime) as nextdate, 
    convert(time, DateAdd(hour, 1, date + time), 108) as nextTime 
    from tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for sql-server 2008+:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  date, 
  time, 
  value, 
  CAST(DATEADD(hh, 1, date + time) as DATE) extdate, 
  CAST(DATEADD(hh, 1, date + time) as time(0)) nextTime 
FROM yourtable
```